# Splitting a string "2014008445" into 2 parts - 20 and 14008445

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have column values like "2014008445" and I need to split them as "20" in a column and "14008445" in another column. The data type of the column is varchar. I need to split and save the values into another column

```
2000001806
2000001801
2000001807
2000001798
2000001811
2000001812
2000001814
2000001810
2000001813
2000001815
```

I have to split the above values into 2 columns where first column values must be 20 and second column values must be remaining part.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you need to split the string where you encounter "20" or do you need to split the first two characters from the rest of the string?

Answer (score 0):

Use *Left* and *substring* functions

```
select Left(value, 2) as col1,
       substring(value, 3, len(value)) as col2
from your table
```

Comment: is this right ??? I am trying to pass in this way 
select Left(2000001806, 2) as col1,
       substring(2000001806, 3, len(10)) as col2

Comment: yeah.. better to put the string inside len function instead of 10.

Comment: select Left(2000001806, 2) as col1,
       substring(2000001806, 3, len(2000001806)) as col2.... when i tried this..the error was this Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function. tell me clearly how to pass the values

Comment: put the value inside single quotes

Comment: k got it..now i need to do the same thing for all the values in the table..how shall i do that.. i have around  948612 records...so i have to get the values and save in the table..how should i need to do that inorder to get the old values, newvalue1 (2 digits) , newvalue2 (8 digits) and the remianing columns in the tables

Comment: in my query replace the yourtabe with your table name and value with your column name

Comment: i need to store the values in the table along with the remaining cloumns in the table..so i need to add two cloumns in the table and then add these values in the table..so how should i do that..

Comment: select inci_id, Left('inci_id', 2) as id,
       substring('inci_id', 3, len('inci_id')) as key_inci_id
    from lwmain....i did this then i am getting the output as  2000001806 in ci_id.. so how to take the values from lwmain table  (inci_id column) as save in the same table with the two extra colmns
2000001801 in ci_id
2000001807 in ci_id
2000001798 in ci_id
2000001811 in ci_id
2000001812 in ci_id
2000001814 in ci_id
2000001810 in ci_id
2000001813 in ci_id
2000001815 in ci_id..

Comment: @Krishna - can you add the above information in question

Comment: elect inci_id, Left('inci_id', 2) as id, substring('inci_id', 3, len('inci_id')) as key_inci_id from lwmain.. worked..now i added two cloumns in the table  ie., "id", "key_inci_id"..i need to update the newly added columns with the values...so how would i do dat..at a time..in the same table..it should update all the records at a time

Comment: Need more information about all the columns in the table for the best solution to do this. But you have some options, With an update statement or a couple of them actually if all the values in this column are unique  something like Update table Set col1 = LEFT('colwithvalue',) from table t1 join table t2 on t1.colwithvalue = t2.colwithvalue then just do the same with the second column and the SUBSTRING function you were given above.

Comment: @Krishna From the explaination above I made an example to show you what I mean  
`CREATE TABLE #stuff (col1 Varchar(32), col2 VARCHAR(32), col3 VARCHAR(32));  

INSERT INTO #stuff (col1) values ('2000001806'),  
('2000001801'),  
('2000001807'),  
('2000001798'),  
('2000001811'),  
('2000001812'),  
('2000001814'),  
('2000001810'),  
('2000001813'),  
('2000001815');  

UPDATE t1  SET col2 = LEFT(t1.col1, 2)
FROM #stuff t1
JOIN #stuff t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1  

UPDATE t1
SET col3 = substring(t1.col1, 3, len(t1.col1)) 
FROM #stuff t1
JOIN #stuff t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1`

Answer (score 0):

Use [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) methods in SQL Server.

[Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/20877)

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(yourColumn, 2),
  SUBSTRING(yourColumn, 3, 9999)
FROM yourTable
```